# Iterate through PyMongo Cursor as key-value pair

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Is it possible to iterate over a pymongo `Cursor` as a key-value pair like a `dict`? I'm using python 2.6 and pymongo 1.9.

I've tried this:

```
import pymongo
mongo = pymongo.Connection('localhost')
mongo_db = mongo['my_database']
mongo_coll = mongo_db['my_collection']
cursor = mongo_coll.find()
records = dict([(record_id, record) for record_id, record in mongo_cursor])
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
records = dict((record['_id'], record) for record in cursor)
```

Answer (score -1):

this is a fuction in python I used to build a JSON response from a MongoDB cursor

```
def build_contacts_cursor(cursor):
    ''' Builds a JSON response for a given cursor
    '''
    response = json.loads('{}')
    response_to_append_to = response['results'] = []

    for idx, bp in enumerate(cursor):
        response_to_append_to.append(bp)

    return response
```

Comment: 2 things. 1) `response = {}` would be a lot more clear than `json.loads('{}')`. 2) You should do `for bp in cursor` because you are ignoring `idx` from `enumerate()`.